# How can I recover text from the Snap app 'Notes'?

Tags: data-recovery

How can I recover text from the Snap app 'Notes'?

After some nearby lightning the motherboard is toast...but the SSD is intact. Other files are OK, but I have lost all my current notes which were in the little snap app 'Notes' by Ruby Mamistvalove.

I've looked here :

volume de 500 GB home / joe / snap / notes

but the 3 folders are empty - 4, common and current. Is this where the app would normally store text or am I looking in the wrong place?

On a new PC I've now installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and started the Snap app 'Notes' but it doesn't show the old texts! Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Check out hidden files. I did found my notes in the location you provided. For me it was `/home/user/snap/notes/current/.config/Awesomeness/Notes.ini`

Comment: @RA that looks like a real answer to me. Consider making it an answer so it can be upvoted.

Comment: Thanks user535733, but I don't see .config/Awsomeness/notes.ini - I get 'folder empty' and there's a purple cicle with a white arrow, what does that mean?

Comment: OK, so it's a link to somewhere but it's not clickable...I have 2 SSDs so maybe I'm not allowed to follow the link on this ( my previous ) SSD?

Comment: @FrenchieJoe You should enable hidden files in your file manager. For me it's Ctrl+H

Answer (score 0):

The notes are stored in a text file here:

```
~/snap/notes/current/.config/Awesomeness/Notes.ini
```